# How to control volume on Philips monitor

Tags: keyboard, audio

So I just installed a 48" monitor with extended display in my home office, however, I can no longer use the f10 - f12 keys to control the volume.

I a colleague provided this guide:
https://www.lifewire.com/select-audio-in-and-out-from-mac-menu-bar-2260855

This did place the volume icon in the menu bar, but its greyed out. I still cannot change the volume.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to go behind the display and use the small joystick/button to lower the brightness of the display.

Answer (score 2):

The volume for most displays can only be controlled externally (i.e., from the monitor itself).

However, there is a workaround that is documented at [Lifehacker](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-enable-mac-volume-control-for-hdmi-or-displaypor-1793607216).

Comment: yeah I saw two articles on that Soundflower, but I have never heard of it before so I am not sure if its a good idea for the health of my system to download.

Comment: I've used Soundflower extensively before. It's probably the most popular free option for routing audio between applications on macOS. It's also [open source.](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower)